# Real-time sync between Oracle DB (source) and Grakn (destination)

Tags: oracle, vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

Is there a tool to synchronise an Oracle and a Grakn database in real time? I couldn't find any information online so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I know Grakn offers GRPC through its client drivers which I'm assuming is the way to go to push things into Grakn.

And I'm aware there are triggers in the Oracle tables, but not sure if will slow down the application layer on the Oracle DB. How would this impact the performance of the BD?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any such tools that you can use OOTB. If you need to keep the Oracle system running then I think you've got two options:

1. Intercept the data as it comes in and dispatch to both Oracle and Grakn.
2. Find a triggering mechanism, and as you outline, read from Oracle and push the data to Grakn through its driver(s).

GRPC is built in to Grakn's drivers, and is the only way to communicate with a Grakn server. These drivers are optimised as such!